# Nuestro sitio se cae de vez en cuando IIS ¿Es posible que sea un ataque DDOS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, iis

> Hola tenemos un sitio, funciona bien la mayoría del tiempo pero de vez
>   en cuando suele dar una caída de un minuto, estamos usando IIS 8.5
>   como servidor y trabajamos toda la tecnología ASP.NET.

Nuestros servidores están hosteados en [Rackspace](https://www.rackspace.com/cloud) y antes de llegar al servidor tenemos un `Load Balancer Round Robin` activado que envía las peticiones a dos servidores que tienen este mismo sitio en ambos funcionando.

He armado en ambos servidores, un `Performance Monitor` con varios `Counters`, entre este `Request Current` y `Request Queued` para monitorear qué sucede, cuando `pingdom` avisa que una de las dos instancias se cae entonces ingreso a ver el `Performance Monitor`, nos damos cuenta que siempre se cae una instancia debido a que tenemos otro sitio alternativo que también se cae y la cola de `aspv4.0` llega al limite.

El valor de `Request Queued` y `Request Current` a veces en pocos segundos llega a 3000 y es ahí cuando el sitio se cae, ¿es posible que se trate de un ataque *DDOS*?

**EDIT:**  Agrego imagenes de las métricas:

[image: Métricas]

Se puede ver en `Request Current` Y `Request Queued` un número igual pero bastante alto indicando que no son procesadas por alguna razón, por otro lado se puede ver la métrica `Application restarts` que tiene el número 39, indicando que se está reiniciando muchas veces las apps.

**Estas son otras métricas que encontre y que me encuentro analizando:**

[image: Otras métricas que estoy analizando]

Espero que puedan darme una mano y en todo caso de que necesiten información adicional, me encuentro a disposición.

Comment: Hola @Mariano, desde ya muchas gracias. he añadido unas imagenes con métricas , he activado logs del IIS para loguear las request, separadas por hora, mi idea es controlar el incremento de requests desde ahí. Las peticiones se dan por multiples sitios ya que es una app que centraliza consultas de otras empresas. Si, podría ser un bug de la app pero necesito entender bien cual es para avisar al equipo. Las médidas que tome en este momento fue aumentar limites de propiedades asp.net  "queue length" a 10000 y Threads per Procesor Limit a 50 . Muchas gracias

Comment: Cuánto es lo normal en el queue de peticiones, y en el request current? A mí más bien me parece que tu aplicación se cae por un error interno, y mientras se vuelve a levantar se encolan peticiones de modo que se produce una especie de denegación de servicio, pero no intencional.

Comment: Como dice @Mariano es posible que haya algún bug en la aplicación y al fallar algo todos los clientes empiecen a hacer peticiones y peticiones hasta que colapsa todo, no siempre tiene que ser algo externo.
Aun así, no sé si en Rackspace os pueden ofrecer algún tipo de servicio de protección DDOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, hace aproximadamente 1 mes detecte una gran cantidad de request fuera de lo normal procesando el archivo de logs de IIS en una tabla mysql. Entonces comencé a aislar procesos para detectar bien por donde venía el problema. Luego de obtener una pagina sospechosa, al examinarla encontramos un proceso muy mal diseñado que elevaba considerablemente los request y por ende se producían downtimes. La optimizacion de este proceso fue la solución al inconveniente, de todas maneras agradezco enormemente sus colaboraciones.